# App crash when adding UITextview "[UITextView length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, unrecognized-selector

I have a very strange problem with something that is probably easy to solve but I cannot get it to work. I want to add a `UITextview` to a `UITableViewCell` (but I have tried it in a simple view too, it gives me the exact same problem). Whether I do it in storyboard or programmatically, the app crashes (sometimes only the second time the view is shown!) with the message

> -[UITextView length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance <...>

This is where I add the `UITextView` (in `CellForRowAtIndexPath:`). `@property UITextView *description` that I assign it to, which has been synthesized.

```
    //description cell
if([indexPath section] == 2 && [indexPath row] == 0) {
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7.0f, 5.0f, 285.0f, 140.0f)];
    textView.editable = YES;
    textView.delegate = self;
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
    self.description = textView;
}
```

Please let me know if you need more code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try and rename your description property. Every subclass of `NSObject` has a description method from `NSObject` - it is possible that this causes the problem

Comment: I think the problem is in another part of the code. This here looks alright. Is it possible that you're trying to get the text of self.description somewhere, but treats it like a string instead of a text view?

Comment: @Accatyyc, I don't use self.description.text anywhere, I have commented out that line and the app still crashes.

Comment: @Pfitz thank you for pointing that out! Unfortunately I don't have access to my Mac until Tuesday but I will try this then and post if if worked.

Comment: thats why i dont made it an answer ;) but maybe you would have trouble otherwhise - you are allowed to override it but it should return a `NSString`.

Comment: Thank you, once I renamed the description property to something else it worked!

Answer (score 0):

A `UITextView` has no property length. If you try to acces the length of the text in the `UITextView` use its property text to get the `NSString` where you can use the text method.E.g.

```
[[textView text] length];
```

But since i think you are mainly interested in the `NSString` form the `UITextView` just use

```
[textView text]
```

Comment: yes, but that's the thing - I don't call length anywhere, not explicitly anyways. Do you have an idea when it could be called implicitly?

Comment: have a look at the stacktrace on the left side which function call the  length method.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong line is `self.description = textView;`. Use `self.description = textView.text;` instead.

Comment: The problem was, as @Pfitz had correctly pointed it out, that I had used my description property to store a UITextView in it. Once I had renamed it to something else, it worked.